# Material Ui Select opening in row

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to Material Ui, currently trying to implement their `SELECT` component, but it is opening in row instead of column. Do I miss something?

```
const SelectDropDownComponent = ({ options }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <Select
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          displayEmpty
          className={classes.selectEmpty}
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Select on close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqjrh.png)
[Select on open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLuhy.png)

Comment: This code work perfect, I think the issue is in your custom style used in classess, can you try to remove classes and run it? or share your style formControl, selectEmpty here too.

Comment: I tried removing that also, styles are same as given in material ui page https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#select

Comment: I too see no problem with the code. Can you reproduce it in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) ?

Comment: I fixed this by adding `flex-direction: column` in `ul` tag

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I got around it by specifying the style as follows:

```
<Select
        MenuProps={{
          MenuListProps: {
            sx: {
              "li.MuiButtonBase-root": {
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
              },
            },
          },
        }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34498120)